# Converting HTML to Pdf

Tags: sharepoint-online, form, html, pdf, document-converter

I have got an html form in SharePoint. I need to generate a pdf from it on a button click. Any suggestions which approach to follow here?

Comment: What do you mean with 'an HTML Form', a SharePoint List item? Is this SharePoint Online or on-premise? Do you have the ability to deploy your own custom code, or 3rd party solutions? There are loads of different options, but all include custom coding or off-the-shelf 3rd party products.

Comment: We could go with third party paid solution but client will only pay one time. Not recurrently.

Comment: For low volume there is a free version (SP Online, Flow, API) at http://www.muhimbi-online.com/Pricing (Disclaimer, I work on that product)

Answer (score 2):

The following JS plugins with source code for your reference.

[html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf)

[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

[PDF Converter Services Online](https://github.com/Muhimbi/PDF-Converter-Services-Online)

Answer (score 1):

We were having similar requirement in project and we used [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) plug-in which is very flexible and easy to use.

You can find it's documentation in below link:

[pdfmake getstarted](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted)

Also you can play with this plug-in using below link:

[pdfmake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)

**Useful links:**

1. [Generate PDF from HTML using pdfMake in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs)

**Note:** This is not a promotional answer. This is free and best plug-in to generate pdf files.

Comment: But I didn't see any option for using dynamic styling like bootstrap to generate the pdf. This is nice plugin but might not work for our scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is not be possible without using any third party service. I will suggest you find any third-party tools and this tools configured with SharePoint and then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The client side libraries had page break issues with the SharePoint. I had to finally generate the pdf server side in an azure function and call this function from my content editor webpart.