# Sharepoint print to pdf

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow

I am looking for help with my power apps / SharePoint online solution I am building. I created a canvas app from a SharePoint list. I need to figure out how to print the form or Sharepoint list item to pdf.

I am not that experienced with HTML, I tried creating an HTML template and having the MS flow override the data in the HTML template. What is the best solution? I have a deadline of Friday 10/4.

Comment: Check my answers given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266191/how-to-download-sharepoint-page-in-pdf-format/266197#266197) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254769/converting-html-to-pdf/254770#254770). You might found something helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this was not available in PowerApps. But I could find this [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-PowerApps-Formerly/Saving-Powerapps-form-as-PDF-or-directly-printing-it/td-p/138842) in the PowerApps forum. Have you tried the solution given there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try working with Word. It's a premium feature in Flow, but it allows you to use a Word file that you have stored in a document library on the same SharePoint site.

In this Word file you can define fields through the Developer tab that can be accessed through Flow.

The Flow command you are looking for is 'Populate a Microsoft Word template'. Once it is in Word you can use action 'Convert Word Documents to PDF'.

[image]